# Why ASP.Net core returns 400 by default if the request is not Json when it should

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-415

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-status-codes) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) docs a 415 status code is:

Microsoft:

> HTTP_STATUS_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA
>
> 415
>
> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of
>   the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for
>   the requested method.

Mozilla

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code
>   indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the
>   payload format is in an unsupported format.

Why if I set the content-type to JSON and send an XML as a request body I get 400  by default when I should get 415?

What is the best way to get 415 when request is not in a valid JSON format? I achieved it using a resource filter, but I am thinking that it would be a waste to read request body twice each time **if** there is other way.

here is my code:

```
public class MyResourceFilter:Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
        var requestBodyText = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
        context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        try
        {
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(requestBodyText);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Result= new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But it does support the media type you *claimed* you were going to send it. The fact that it cannot process the data means that you've made a mistake, but it's not due to *it* not supporting JSON.

Comment: Why do you want to get 415 in the first place?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen because I thought it should be, according to Mozilla "the payload format is in an unsupported format"

Comment: Consider also that multiple independent types of content may have byte-for-byte identical representations. That's why we need things like `Content-Type` in the first place. If it was possible for servers to just *inspect the content* and know what you'd sent, `Content-Type` wouldn't need to exist.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for the insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's incorrect to return a 415 in this case. That status code literally means the server doesn't support the mime-type, which in this case is `application/json`. The server very much *does* support that type, so it's not going to return a 415. A 400 Bad Request is the correct response status code to return, because the you told it was JSON, but you sent XML instead, i.e. *you made a bad request*.